# How to organize output table of grouped summary statics of multiple statistics across multiple variables?

Tags: r, tables

Currently my output stems from the follow code:

```
echo_sum <- echo_sub %>%
  group_by(sercs_studyg) %>%
  summarise(across(.cols = everything(), 
           .fns = list(median = ~ median(.x,na.rm = TRUE),
           iqr= ~IQR(.x,na.rm = TRUE), n = ~length(.x)),
           groups = 'keep'))
```

This gives the following output:
[image: output]

As you can see I have a variable for the group, and each variable now has 3 statistics: Median, IQR, and N. (sercs_ejct = sercs_ejct_median, sercs_ejct_iqr, and sercs_ejct_n).

I'm curious if I can create a gt table where the study group (column 1) is a spanner column label, and the median, IQR, and N are column labels, and the variable name (sercs_ejct,...) is the row name. I'm not sure if I need to approach generating the output in a different way to achieve the desired outcome, or first manipulate the output using a pivot_longer or something along those lines.